# How can I programatically evaluate each pixel before final composition?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, compositing-nodes

I'm using a complex compositor node setup, which in the end reduces the image to just a few solid colors. I would like to remove any pixels from the image which have no pixels of the same color in the 8 surrounding pixels (and replace them with whatever color is most common in those 8 pixels). I don't want to affect any of the other pixels.

Is there any method within the compositor I could use to do this?

Comment: Some of the sampling facilities  may provide an average of the surrounding pixels and assign that color to multiple pixels.... pixelation.  Division by X, Truncate, Multiply by (1/X)
 ... quantization.  Some of the tools which read in a texture may do this.  Compositor has pixelate node.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

An example of a pixelated image in the compositor.  This may help for one part of your question.